# UPDATE COLUMN OF RESULTSET IN SSIS

Tags: ssis

I would like to update the column document path of a resultset from a SELECT Statement in 'Execute SQL Task' in SSIS which generates document paths as company\doc_ID. What is the best way to achieve this, if I want to change each document path of each document from company\doc_ID to tm\doc_ID?

Comment: I'm a little slow on the uptake, could you provide some sample source data, the query you're using and the expected output?

Comment: I have done some searches on how to update multiple rows to different values and did not come up with any clear and easy methods. I use the foreach loop in SSIS to execute the select statement: select doc_ID, doc_title, doc_path from table X where doc_title in ( 'ADD12','BBA01',...). This results in documents with Paths such as doc_path\doc_ID. The resulting Document's path is 'Company\doc_ID' and now I need to change the path to 'TM\doc_ID' or in other words, how do I update all documents with its individual ID attached to the common path 'TM'?